# Manufacturer questions about USB 3.0 differential pair spacing in PCB design

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, layout, pcb-layers

After sending a re-design to MFG I got the following question.
can someone please explain the notation 4.7/7.3/4.7 mill and the contradiction that the MFG found?

[image]
[image]

Note:
we are talking about USB3 traces.
trace width: 4.7 mil, spacing width: 9 mil.
[image]
[image]

Comment: You requested a 90 ohms trace which is not 90 ohms with the defined pair spacing and layer stackup geometry. You must change the spacing/stackup in order to get a 90 ohms trace.

Comment: They are telling you that they don't think they can achieve 90 Ohms on layer 10 because the space between diff pair traces is not 7.3 mils. The highlighted traces on the right are the ones whose spacing is not right (according to the fab house).

Comment: The notation 4.7/7.3/4.7 means diff pair with 4.7 mil traces and 7.3 mil gap between traces.

Comment: What are those traces for? That is a pretty short area where the spacing is wrong, and the board might work fine the way it is if that is the only violation.

Comment: @mkeith Please see the edit.

Comment: The USB spec calls for a mated connector impedance of 75Ω to 105Ω but changes in impedance might not be ideal

Comment: Unless time is very, very critical, the ideal resolution would be to fix the design and regenerate gerbers with 7.3 spacing for USB everywhere on layer 10. That is the right way to do it. That is my recommendation. But as I said, if that is the only area where the impedance is not right, it will probably be OK. It would definitely be OK for USB 2.0 hi-speed. But I haven't done 3.0. Maybe it is more demanding. So you have to decide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can someone please explain the notation 4.7/7.3/4.7 mill

This means a differential pair with 4.7 mil trace width and 7.3 mil space between traces.

> ... and the contradiction that the MFG found

In your fab notes, you told the vendor that differential pairs with 4.7 mil trace width and 7.3 mil spacing are intended as 90-ohm controlled impedance pairs.

But then you drew your traces with 9 mil spacing instead of 7.3 mil spacing.

First you need to work out whether 7.3 mil or 9 mil is the correct spacing to achieve 90 ohm differential controlled impedance. Depending on the vendor, they might be able to provide this information.

Then you can either change the design to use 7.3 mils, or change the note to call out 9 mils as the correct spacing.